# Programatically editing a another applications config file from a web service?

Tags: c#, .net, web-services

I am trying to edit a config file of another application with my Web Service.
Currently I have:

```
  [WebMethod]
    public string EditConfig(string path)
    {

        string cfgPath = Path.Combine(path, "Compressor.exe.config");
        var configMap = new ExeConfigurationFileMap { ExeConfigFilename = cfgPath };

        var cf = ConfigurationManager.OpenMappedExeConfiguration(configMap,
            ConfigurationUserLevel.None);

        string hello = cf.AppSettings.Settings["SaveTo"].Value;
        return hello;

        //cf.AppSettings.Settings["RandomAddedKey"].Value = "Hello World!";
        //cf.Save();
    }
```

I have also tried:

```
var config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(path);
var hello = config.AppSettings.Settings["SaveTo"].Value;
return hello;
```

Sadly I haven't had success with any of these, and before resorting to the XML Editor I needed to make sure that this isn't possible or I am doing something wrong?
I have searched through StackOverFlow and the best results returned me an "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." Exception.

I have tried feeding the exe to the path the config and only the directory in several different applications.

In this case I want the Web Service to tell the Compressor what to compress and where to save it, but in the code I am just experimenting to get it working.

I am using .NET Framework 3.5 (Latest for web services).
I have tried editing apps in different kinds of framework versions and the end result was the same.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are passing in a path from the client to the server.   How does the client know what the server's path should be?

Comment: @SteveWellens, It's only for testing purposes, obviously the service will not ask for the path, because I was trying different applications. What this Service will do is use Task Manager to set a task on when should the compressor run (it does that) but i want to pass in information to the compressor what to compress and where to save it.
I hope I answered (understood) your question.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If I get it right, what you want to do is manipulate a configuration file of **another application** programmatically. Your problems have nothing to do with doing your manipulation inside a web service application. While I think it is relatively easy to manipulate a configuration file through the very same application, it is not such an easy task to do it from another application. I would suggest two approaches:

1. Use the .NET API to do it. [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228054.ASPX) you can find an example of manipulating configuration files remotely.
2. You could manipulate the specific configuration file, as every other XML file using the respective .NET libraries. [Here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/301233) you can see how to do it.

Hope I helped!

Comment: You misunderstood, I do not want to edit the servers configuration file, I want to edit the configuration file in the clients app.
I am thinking of resorting to the XML editor at this point, seems like I can't find an answer... =/